# Implementing StringLiteralConvertible on NSURL in Swift 1.1

Tags: swift

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24101368/265072) is an older question on the same topic, but it is for Swfit 1.0. In Swift 1.1, the `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol has changed to use initializers instead of class methods. Also, `[NSURL init(string: String)]` become a failable initializer.

This is what I've tried but it doesn't compile in Xcode 6.1.

```c
extension NSURL: StringLiteralConvertible {
  convenience public init?(stringLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(string: value)
  }

  convenience public init?(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(string: value)
  }

  convenience public init?(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
    self.init(string: value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The initializers required by the protocol "StringLiteralConvertible" do not return optionals, so putting a ? after init won't help (even though XCode itself suggests it). But all initializers for NSURL *do* return optionals, because the parameters may not result in a valid URL. And you have to call one of the super.init initializers in all custom NSURL initializers. So it is no longer possible to have NSURL implement "StringLiteralConvertible".