# Create an NSURL from a string literal in Swift

Tags: swift

This has been asked before:

[Implementing StringLiteralConvertible on NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101368/implementing-stringliteralconvertible-on-nsurl)

However, [changes in Xcode 6.1](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/09/10/changes-to-the-swift-standard-library-in-xcode-6-1/), mean that this answer is no longer correct. This is my code so far:

```
extension NSURL: StringLiteralConvertible {

  typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType = String
  typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType = String

  convenience public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType){
    self.init(string: value)!
  }

  convenience public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType){
    self.init(string: value)!
  }

  convenience public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType){
    self.init(string: value)!
  }
}
```

Note the addition of the unicode scalar literal type, which was introduced in 6.1.

However, the above code fails for a few reasons, the most significant being this one:

> Initializer requirement 'init(stringLiteral:)' can only be satisfied by a `required` initializer in the definition of non-final class 'NSURL'

Which indicates that the initialisers should be marked as `required`. However, required initialisers cannot be defined in extensions.

Unless I am mistaken, these changes to the Swift language make it impossible to add literal conversion functionality to to types other than those you have created yourself.

Comment: I think this is incorrectly marked as a duplicate, since this question is subtly different.  This one is about why they can't all be declared convenience initializers, whereas that one is more about why they can't be failable - though admittedly, once past that, the other question would then hit the convenience issue...

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: Both are about the (im)possibility of implementing StringLiteralConvertible for NSURL, I do not see the difference in the question.

Comment: Just because both are about issues relating to implementing `StringLiteralConvertible` does not make them the same question. They are about two separate issues relating to implementing it.  Colin's question explicitly recognizes the issue with `NSURL.init` being failable while `init(stringLiteral:)` isn't, wheras the other question doesn't.

Comment: Where does Colin mention failable initializers in this question?

Comment: He explicitly force-unwraps the result of `self.init(string: value)`, and declares the inits themselves without a `?`.  Unlike the other question which is attempting to implement `StringLiteralConvertible` fallibly.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity:  Both questions ask how to create an NSURL from a string literal and how to adapt the solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101368/implementing-stringliteralconvertible-on-nsurl to Swift 1.1. The attempts are slightly different, but the other question also mentions the failable initializer. – If you *really* think that this deserves a separate answer than I have no problems reopening the question. In my opinion it is the same problem and it would be better to have one "canonical" question and add more answers to that, if necessary.